# how to redirect on single type of url

Tags: html, .htaccess, dns, cross-domain

I want to redirect on single domain URL on like this `https://www.example.com/`
when user will type any one of belove URL

```
https://example.com/ or
www.example.com or
http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\/ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this is not redirecting from this URL www.example.com/

Comment: The answer has been updated. Try the latest edit. I hope that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^index$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

this works for me